# Meaning of a probability on a product defined by a transition probability

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If $(\Omega,\mathbb{B},P)$ and $(\Omega',\mathbb{B}')$ are sets with sigma algebras and $P$ is a probability on $(\Omega,\mathbb{B})$. If $\nu(\omega,B')$ is a transition probability from $(\Omega,\mathbb{B})$ to $(\Omega',\mathbb{B}')$ (that is $\nu(.,B')$ is measurable for all $B'$ and $\nu(\omega,.)$ is a probability on $(\Omega',\mathbb{B}')$), then one can define $\mu$, a probability on $(\Omega\times\Omega',\mathbb{B}\otimes\mathbb{B}')$ which verifies $\mu(B\times B')=\int_{B}\!\nu(\omega,B')\,\mathrm{d}P$ (cf. ***Calcul des probabilités*** by Neveu, p70).

I am wondering what is the meaning of $\mu$. Does it verify a uniqueness property more intelligible ? (I understand that if $\nu(.,B')=\alpha(B')$ is constant, then $\mu=P\otimes\alpha$)

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov chains?

Comment: Not in their full generality.

Comment: You can think of transition probabilities as the general abstract equivalent of the transition matrix in a Markov chain.